# Python v3.3 encode('hex')

Tags: python-3.x, hex, encode

Has HEX codec been excluded from Python 3.3? When I write the code

```py
>>> s="Hallo"
>>> s.encode('hex')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#24>", line 1, in <module>
    s.encode('hex')
LookupError: unknown encoding: hex
```

What does that mean? I know about `binascii.hexlify()` but still `.encode()` method is nice!

Any suggestion?

Comment: there is http://bugs.python.org/issue7475

Comment: SO, 'hex' code is missing! Is there any way to add that codec or method, there are two files on your link, what does that do?

Comment: To convert **numbers** in hex, you can still use `hex(n)`.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

No, using `encode()` to hexlify isn't nice.

The way you use the `hex` codec worked in Python 2 because you can call `encode()` on 8-bit strings in Python 2, ie you can encode something that is already encoded. That doesn't make sense. `encode()` is for encoding Unicode strings into 8-bit strings, not for encoding 8-bit strings as 8-bit strings.

In Python 3 you can't call `encode()` on 8-bit strings anymore, so the `hex` codec became pointless and was removed.

Although you theoretically could have a `hex` codec and use it like this:

```
>>> import codecs
>>> hexlify = codecs.getencoder('hex')
>>> hexlify(b'Blaah')[0]
b'426c616168'
```

Using binascii is easier and nicer:

```
>>> import binascii
>>> binascii.hexlify(b'Blaah')
b'426c616168'
```

Comment: binascii.hexlify() need buffer interface, right? So, can somebody please explain me how to perform formatting on buffer interface?

Comment: @iMagur: Sorry, I forgot to make the code Python 3 code, since I made it in Python 2 (as the hex_codec doesn't exist in Python 3). This has now been fixed. The above binascii code works in Python 3, and shows you how to do it. 

In Python 3 strings are Unicode, so they can't be hexlified directly, you need to encode them as `bytes` first.

Comment: This is good because frankly there is a lot of 8 bit usage going on out there. Particularly between ('ascii') , ('IBM500'), ('IBM037').
What was really needed out of the box was a number of "OD" style hex methods for strings. Python is chosen to reduce effort and these things double the code required..  Yes I know IBM500 is unicode..

Answer (score 2):

this is the same answer for the above but i modified it so it works with python 3.

```
import binascii
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto import Random

def encrypt(passwrd, message):
    msglist = []
    key = bytes(passwrd, "utf-8")
    iv = Random.new().read(AES.block_size)
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CFB, iv)
    msg = iv + cipher.encrypt(bytes(message, "utf-8"))
    msg = binascii.hexlify(msg)
    for letter in str(msg):
        msglist.append(letter)
    msglist.remove("b")
    msglist.remove("'")
    msglist.remove("'")
    for letter in msglist:
        print(letter, end="")
    print("")

def decrypt(passwrd, message):
    msglist = []
    key = bytes(passwrd, "utf-8")
    iv = Random.new().read(AES.block_size)
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CFB, iv)
    msg = cipher.decrypt(binascii.unhexlify(bytes(message, "utf-8")))[len(iv):]
    for letter in str(msg):
        msglist.append(letter)
    msglist.remove("b")
    msglist.remove("'")
    msglist.remove("'")
    for letter in msglist:
        print(letter, end="")
    print("")
```

Answer (score 0):

regebro's answer is right but if you need to define a **variable** this code may help.C is a str here.

```
import codecs

c='sdfds'
print(codecs.encode(c))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.