# python, hex values to convert to a string/integer

Tags: python, string, hex

I'm looking how I can take hex values, and turn them into a string or an integer.
Examples:

```
>>> a = b'\x91\x44\x77\x65\x92'
>>> b = b'\x44\x45\x41\x44\x42\x45\x45\x46'
>>> a
>>> �Dwe�
>>> b
>>> 'DEADBEEF'
```

Desired results for **a** and **b**:

```
>>> 9144776592
>>> '4445414442454546'
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
>>> a = b'\x91\x44\x77\x65\x92'
>>> a.encode("hex")
'9144776592'
>>> b.encode('hex')
'4445414442454546'
```

Note, that it's not nice to use `encode('hex')` - here's an [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13435922/python-encode) why:

> The way you use the hex codec worked in Python 2 because you can call
>   encode() on 8-bit strings in Python 2, ie you can encode something
>   that is already encoded. That doesn't make sense. encode() is for
>   encoding Unicode strings into 8-bit strings, not for encoding 8-bit
>   strings as 8-bit strings.
>
> In Python 3 you can't call encode() on 8-bit strings anymore, so the
>   hex codec became pointless and was removed.

Using [binascii](http://docs.python.org/2/library/binascii.html) is easier and nicer, it is designed for conversions between binary and ascii, it'll work for both python 2 and 3:

```
>>> import binascii
>>> binascii.hexlify(b'\x91\x44\x77\x65\x92')
b'9144776592'
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`binascii.hexlify`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/binascii#binascii.hexlify):

```
In [1]: from binascii import hexlify

In [2]: a = b'\x91\x44\x77\x65\x92'

In [3]: hexlify(a)
Out[3]: b'9144776592'

In [4]: b = b'\x44\x45\x41\x44\x42\x45\x45\x46'

In [5]: hexlify(b)
Out[5]: b'4445414442454546'
```

If you want `str` instead of bytes:

```
In [7]: hexlify(a).decode('ascii')
Out[7]: '9144776592'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [binascii.hexlify](http://docs.python.org/3/library/binascii#binascii.hexlify):

```
>>> import binascii
>>> a = b'\x91\x44\x77\x65\x92'
>>> b = b'\x44\x45\x41\x44\x42\x45\x45\x46'
>>> binascii.hexlify(a)
b'9144776592'
>>> binascii.hexlify(b)
b'4445414442454546'
```