# get UTF-8 encoded hex value for international character

Tags: python, python-2.7, shell, unicode, utf-8

Using Mac OSX and if there is a file encoded with UTF-8 (contains international characters besides ASCII), wondering if any tools or simple command (e.g. in Python 2.7 or shell) we can use to find the related hex (base-16) values (in terms of byte stream)? For example, if I write some Asian characters into the file, I can find the related hex value.

My current solution is I open the file and read them byte by byte using Python str. Wondering if any simpler ways without coding. :)

**Edit 1**, it seems the output of `od` is not correct,

```
cat ~/Downloads/12
1

od ~/Downloads/12
0000000    000061
0000001
```

**Edit 2**, tried `od -t x1` options as well,

```
od -t x1 ~/Downloads/12
0000000    31
0000001
```

thanks in advance,
Lin

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "related hex" in this case.  Using the Terminal.app in Mac OS X with a bash shell, it's trivial to grep for Unicode characters outside the US-ASCII range.  Something like: `grep 中国 cn.txt` Are you trying to find linguistically similar characters, near a codepoint range or something else?

Comment: @LexScarisbrick, nice example. The hex value I mean the real byte values which is encoded as UTF-8. The reason why I want to get hex value is because I may need to assign variable values like `\xE3\x80\x82` in Python 2.7, which are the byte values hex form for an unicode character. I am not doing grep. If you have any ideas, it will be great.

Comment: `od` is the POSIX hex dump tool. Not a programming question; voting to close.

Comment: Python 2 has a hex codec in its standard library; you don't need an external tool. For Python 3, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13435922/python-encode

Comment: You can absolutely assign variables with Unicode characters (e.g. `foo = u'\u3002'`). It's still not clear why you would want to work directly with a UTF-8 encoded byte stream as opposed to decoded character strings.  Something to keep in mind is that UTF-8 encoded characters are _variable_ _length_ and anywhere between 1 and 4 bytes long.  Further reading: [http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: @LexScarisbrick, I know how to use `u` prefix to assign, my question is, I do not know the unicode value (e.g. `3002` in your example), I only know the international character, and it is why I want to write this international character into a text file, and then get its related hex values of UTF-8 (e.g. `3002` in your example). If you have any better ideas how to resolve this problem, it will be great. Vote up for your reply.

Comment: @tripleee, nice ideas and vote up for your both posts. I am going to write some international characters and save into UTF-8 encoding to have a try. Do you know which tools on Mac supports encoding plain text into different encoding, like UTF-8, ITF-16, etc? I tried Atom and TextEdit, it seems neither of them give me a choice of encoding methods when saving. Thanks.

Comment: @tripleee, I tried `od`, the output seems not correct, please refer to Edit 1 section of my original post.

Comment: Just to be clear, are you hoping to print the Unicode code points or the byte values of the encoded byte stream? For example, for the single character `我`, do you want to see the Unicode code point `6211` or the UTF-8-encoded byte stream `e6 88 91`?

Comment: @Robᵩ, byte values. Thanks and vote up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`od` is the right command, but you need to specify an optional argument `-t x1`:

```
$ od -t x1 ~/Downloads/12
0000000 31
0000001
```

If you prefer not to see the file offsets, try adding `-A none`:

```
$ od -A none -t x1 ~/Downloads/12
 31
```

Additionally, the Linux man page (but not the OS X man page) lists this example: `od -A x -t x1z -v`, "Display hexdump format output."

Reference:
http://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/1/od/

Comment: Thanks Robᵩ, vote up. I post the command output in Edit 2 section, think the output should only be `31`, what does `0000000` and `0000001` mean?

Comment: Those are the offsets into the data file. So the first line represents offset 0, the next line, being empty, represents the end of the file at offset 1. Try a larger file to see how those offsets work. If you don't want to see the offsets, try adding `-A none`.

Comment: Thanks Robᵩ, your solution works. Vote up and mark your reply as answer.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure exactly what you want, but this script can help you look up the Unicode codepoint and UTF-8 byte sequence for any character.  Be sure to save the source as UTF-8.

```
# coding: utf8
s = u'我是美国人。'
for c in s:
    print c,'U+{:04X} {}'.format(ord(c),repr(c.encode('utf8')))
```

Output:

```
我 U+6211 '\xe6\x88\x91'
是 U+662F '\xe6\x98\xaf'
美 U+7F8E '\xe7\xbe\x8e'
国 U+56FD '\xe5\x9b\xbd'
人 U+4EBA '\xe4\xba\xba'
。 U+3002 '\xe3\x80\x82'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the command `iconv` to convert between encodings.  The basic command is:

```
iconv -f from_encoding -t to_encoding inputfile
```

and you can see a list of supported encodings with

```
iconv --list
```

In your case,

```
iconv -f UTF8 -t UCS-2 inputfile
```

You've also asked to see the hex values.  A standard utility that will do this is `xxd`.  You can pipe the results of `iconv` to `xxd` as follows:

```
iconv -f UTF8 -t UCS-2 inputfile | xxd
```

Comment: Thanks borrible, vote up. I do not need to convert, I just need to see its existing hex values. Want to confirm it is what I need? Thanks.

Comment: Your question's title looks like this is what you are asking for, but the actual question looks like it definitely isn't. We can't really know, can we?

Comment: @tripleee, nice catch. I re-read my title and update it. Vote up for your recommendations.