# Constructing AWS S4 authentication in python

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, hmac

I'm trying to create S4 signatures as outlined [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-v4-examples.html#signature-v4-examples-python) using the python code snippet. The documentation is confusing me so I wanted some clarity on the following

1) The getSignatureKey method is signing 4 inputs, but the output they have shown has an extra kSecret. What is this kSecret?

2) When I run the program, the output I get is like this:

```
kDate = '\x96\x9f\xbb\x94\xfe\xb5B\xb7\x1e\xdeo\x87\xfeM_\xa2\x9cx\x93B\xb0\xf4\x07GFp\xf0\xc2H\x9e\n\r'
```

whereas the output as per the documentation is like this:

```
kDate    = '969fbb94feb542b71ede6f87fe4d5fa29c789342b0f407474670f0c2489e0a0d'
```

Which is the correct format to be used? How to get one from the other?

3) It appears that the output values are also different (if I strip away the \x). Is this a documentation error?

I am using python 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`kSecret` is the hex-encoded representation of your original aws-access-key-secret.  Some of the other language examples have an intermediate variable for this.

The output shown for the various keys is only shown for convenience:

> Note that these are hex-encoded representations of the binary data; the key itself and the intermediate values should be in binary format.

I am not versed in python 2, but it looks like [`binascii.hexlify`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13435922/1695906) would be a way to accomplish the conversion.  Just remember this conversion is only for the benefit of your eyeballs.  The actual code uses the binary representations of the intermediate keys.

Comment: So does that mean neither of these representations are used while authenticating?

Comment: The final signature needs to be hex-encoded, but the only reason you would need to do any encoding of the secret/date/region/service/signing keys would be if you want to inspect their values for troubleshooting purposes.  These are all intermediate values that are  needed for signature calculation, but they are all secret values that are not sent with the signed request.