# encode() method in python

Tags: python, function, encoding

If `X = "ABCD"` then encoding the X should show: `\x41\x42\x43\x44`

But why does `X.encoding("utf-8")` shows: `b"ABCD"`

I am having difficulties in understanding how text encoding works in python?

Comment: The two things you showed, are the same thing. The terminal will interpret `\x41` and print `A` for you. `b'\x41' == b'A'` will be `True`. And that's because, again, they're the same - you're just seeing a representation of `\x41`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the correct way to convert bytes to a hex string in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6624453/whats-the-correct-way-to-convert-bytes-to-a-hex-string-in-python-3)

Comment: `bytes` are shown as user-friendly as possible. But both `\x41\x42\x43\x44` and `ABCD` are just two different representations of the same information.

Comment: There's also this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13435922/python-encode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are the same thing - bytes are just shown in human-readable form whenever it's possible. :)

Try it yourself in Python console:

```
>>> b"\x41\x42\x43\x44"
b'ABCD'
>>> "ABCD".encode() == b"\x41\x42\x43\x44"
True
```